# Problems using MySQL inside PHP and trying to get my database to insert into tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use a page called create-order.php to post information from that form into a confirm-order.php that will insert what is put into the table from create-order.php and input the data into my database. I believe I have the sql right but I can't get the data to show up when looking at my table in phpmyadmin.

I've tried setting up variables in confirm-order.php with each variable being posted from the previous webpage and then creating a $sql variable that will be the command to insert the data into the table. My problem is getting the data to show up within phpmyadmin

create-order.php looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Create order</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Create order form</h3>
        <form method="post" action="order-confirm.php">
            <p>Store ID:<input type="text" name="store_id" /></p>
            <p>Console ID:<input type="text" name="console_id" /></p>
            <p>Quantity:<input type="text" name="quantity"</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Create Order" /> &nbsp; <input type="reset" value = "Reset Order"/></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

order-confirm.php looks like this:

```
//session_start() has to be called the very first line where a session is used
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$store_id = $_POST['store_id'];
$console_id = $_POST['console_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(Stores_StoreID, Consoles_idConsoles, order) VALUE ($store_id, $console_id, $quantity)";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);




?>
```

I expect the data to be inserted into the table but it is not.

Comment: If a query does not work, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out why. MySQL errors report differently than regular PHP errors. Also, you are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Please check you database sql connection.

Comment: Check your html form file. input for quantity is not closed

Comment: Also, if Stores_StoreID and Consoles_idConsoles are foreign keys, check that the corresponding row exist in their respective table.

Answer (score 2):

`order` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

So, using `order` as a column will cause a syntax error in MySQL. You have two solutions to this:

**1) Enclose backtick to `order`.**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(Stores_StoreID, Consoles_idConsoles, `order`) VALUE ($store_id, $console_id, $quantity)";
```

**2) Prefix table name before order e.g. `orders.order`**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders(Stores_StoreID, Consoles_idConsoles, orders.order) VALUE ($store_id, $console_id, $quantity)";
```